# Very simple toggleClass not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggleclass

So I have some really simple code but it's not working.

```js
$(function() {
 $("#tren").click(function() {
  $("#trens").toggleClass("show");
 });
});
```

```css
.show {
    color: "red";
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li id="tren">Some text</li>
</ul>
<div id="trens">
    <p>Other text</p>
</div>
```

'Other text' is supposed to get red, but it doesn't . What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you include jQuery?

Comment: You cannot, in html have more than once the same id on an element in the whole page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove the quotes in your CSS. Run the snippet below to see it work.

```js
$(function() {
 $("#tren").click(function() {
  $("#trens").toggleClass("show");
 });
});
```

```css
.show {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li id="tren">Some text</li>
</ul>
<div id="trens">
    <p>Other text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Now you only need to press the check button so this question is answered

Comment: I know, I have to wait for 8 more minutes

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is take the word 'red' out of the parentheses.

.show {color: red;}